# PCIe lanes CPU dependent?

Tags: pci-express

Are the number of available PCIe lanes CPU dependent? I ask because of the 5820k and the 5930k differences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no.  The cpu has a certain number of lanes coming out of it.  On desktop Intel cpus, this number is usually 20 lanes, 16 of which are routed to the primary graphics card slot, and the other 4 are dedicated to communicating with the motherboard chipset, and are referred to as the DMI by Intel.  The motherboard chipset appears as a PCI Express bridge, having several devices that are actually internal to the chipset, and several additional lanes that fan out to the other expansion slots.  So there are a fixed number of lanes coming out of the cpu, but bridges can fan those out into more lanes.